# Ansible xml puts value in new node at bottom instead of modifying existing node

Tags: xml, ansible, lxml

I am trying to work with a jboss standalone.xml file, to try to customize it for different environments at the time of deployment. In my xml I have:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
  <extensions></extensions>
  <system-properties>  </system-properties>
  <management>  </management>
  <profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1"></subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.1"></subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
      <datasources>
        <xa-datasource use-ccm="true"  pool-name='MyPoolname'>
          <xa-datasource-property name="URL">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="Password">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="User"> </xa-datasource-property>
        </xa-datasource>
      </datasources>
    </subsystem>
  </profile>
</server>
```

In the above xml, I want to replace the URL of the DB connection with the value contained in config_vars structure
My playbook looks like:

```
  tasks:
    - name: "Update the DB endpoint in {{item.jboss_folder}}"
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      xml:
        path: "/opt/{{item.jboss_folder}}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml"
        namespaces:
          svr: "urn:jboss:domain:1.2"
          ss: "urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"
        xpath: "/svr:server/profile/ss:subsystem/ss:datasources/ss:xa-datadource[@pool-name='MyPoolname']/ss:xa-datasource-property[@name='URL']"
        value: 'mysql://{{item.db_endpoint}}:3306/{{item.db_name}}'
      loop: "{{config_vars}}"
```

The resulting xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
  <extensions/>
  <system-properties>  </system-properties>
  <management>  </management>
  <profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.1"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
      <datasources>
        <xa-datasource use-ccm="true" pool-name="MyPoolname">
          <xa-datasource-property name="URL">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="Password">  </xa-datasource-property>
          <xa-datasource-property name="User"> </xa-datasource-property>
        </xa-datasource>
      </datasources>
    </subsystem>
  </profile>
<profile><ns0:subsystem xmlns:ns0="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0"><ns0:datasources><ns0:xa-datadource pool-name="MyPoolname"><ns0:xa-datasource-property name="URL">mysql://<whatever-my-db-is>:3306/prod</ns0:xa-datasource-property></ns0:xa-datadource></ns0:datasources></ns0:subsystem></profile></server>
```

A new profile tag has appeared in which the sub-tags are like `<ns0:...>`. What is making it create the new node instead of finding the xpath location and assigning the value, and why does it invent that new (and non-existent) namespace name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error of omission in xpath

Original:

`/svr:server/profile/ss:subsystem/ss:datasources/ss:xa-datadource[@pool-name='MyPoolname']/ss:xa-datasource-property[@name='URL']`

Needs to be:

`/svr:server/svr:profile/ss:subsystem/ss:datasources/ss:xa-datadource[@pool-name='MyPoolname']/ss:xa-datasource-property[@name='URL']`